# C# XNA still good

Tags: c#, xna

So I know there are some questions that were created a couple of years ago, but they seem a bit outdated, so bear with me:).

Due to work, where I have some free time if there is nothing to do, I wanted to get more in-depth with programming. Gaming has always been a hobby of mine. So I wanted to check out if it can keep me interested enough for making it my work :).

So finally my question(I just want to give a bit more background info, for the answer of the question.) what is the best to pick up? A lot of people say XNA is outdated and useless. Some say unity is the way to go, but some say that it's garbage.

~~BAMM.
Ps. I'm sorry if I haven't searched good enough, I just couldn't find the answer I was looking for

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Your question seems opinion-based rather than facts. Stack Overflow is for specific programming problems. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XNA](http://create.msdn.com/) is still useful if you want to create games for Windows Phone 8, WP 7, Xbox 360 or Windows OS (Windows XP, Vista and 7).

You also have the similar [MonoGame](http://www.monogame.net/) that allows you to build games for several systems (Windows, Windows Phone, Windows 8, etc) using a framework that is 90% similar to XNA.

[Unity](http://unity3d.com/) is another tool that allows you to create games for different platforms, and after last years E3, Microsoft hinted that it was the way to go for creating games on Xbox One.
Unity allows you to create games for non Windows platforms as well, so does MonoGame.
The thing with Unity is that it is not a free tool, aside from the 30 day free trial you can get, where XNA and MonoGame are.

Another thing to keep in mind is that MonoGame requires you to have XNA installed in your machine in order to work.

Comment: So Unity is the way to go? I am not the best programmer, but I'm definitely not a super beginner, but I only know my way around in C#.

Comment: If you don't mind paying for it, then it's the one recommended by the vast majority. If I'm right, you can even create games for Linux, Android, IOS and Sony with Unity.

Comment: Alright! I'll guess I'll like into Unity. I don't want to be stuck with a language that I learnt that isn't that only for windows :). Thanks!

Comment: Good choice, best of luck :)

Comment: MonoGame **does not** require XNA installed in order to work.

Comment: It did a year ago, last time I used it, in order to generate the xnb files.

Comment: To expand to this a bit: MonoGame will run on Linux, OSX, iOS, Android, Windows, Windows Phone, PS4,Windows 8 apps and more. There is no runtime dependency on XNA, and the content pipeline is being worked on to remove the *build* dependency on XNA, this isn't *always* required